# Middle age roman numerals formatting

Tags: counters, roman-numerals

I've recently read about [a middle age variation on roman numerals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals#Middle_Ages.2FRennaisance) where the last "i" character is replaced by a "j". I was thinking about writing my own `\roman` and `\Roman` variations, but hit a stone wall... does anyone have any idea how one may go about doing something like this?
Thanks in advance!

PS: I'd like to change a final "v" to a "y" while we're at it ;)

edit: clarifying the issue, I'd *only* like to replace the last "i" and "v" in a roman numeral for "j" and "y" respectively. I'm not interested (at the moment at least :P) in every other middle age variation.

Comment: Are you going use it also for counters and calculations or just for typesetting?

Comment: Hmm... on the one hand, i'd like it to behave like `\roman` and `\Roman` (ie. accepting a counter as an argument and producing the typeset numerals); on the other hand, it would be nice to have a `\MiddleAgeRoman` sort of thing that would get a number and typeset it accordingly.

Comment: It is possible, but not easy, especially as the wikipedia article is partially incomplete. The approach is to rather use your own macro, i.e., `\MiddleAgeRoman` I cannot see it possible hacking `\roman` or `\Roman` but I can be wrong. I have posted some code at http://pastebin.com/caS5mAnR, if you modify the table to typest the middle age variation, either me or someone would be able to post the code.

Comment: I've created a revision at [link](http://pastebin.com/DUQcbkQy). It looks admittedly bad in uppercase, it _should_ lok better in lowercase ;)

Comment: If you want only the last `i` to be changed to `j` it will be easier to do. Is that the only change? It doesn't appear to be so from wikipedia.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a start,

```
\def\MiddleAgeRoman#1{%
    \ifcase#1 zero not allowed
    \or i\or ij\or iij\or iv\or v \or vi 
    \or vij \or viij \or ix\or x 
    \else Not available for #1\fi\relax}


    \MiddleAgeRoman{7}
```

Will have a look at the revised link and try and get some more code later.

Also check out the package http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/modroman, it appears to be able to do what you want.

Comment: This works great! (the "custom command" part) I just don't see how I can extend it to accommodate for arbitrary roman numerals... On the other hand, will this work `\pagenumbering{MiddleAgeRoman}`?

Comment: @mpr No it will not work for sectioning commands, if you after that look at http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/romannum

Answer (score 12):

```
\def\Middleage#1{%
  \ifnum#1>0
    \expandafter\Middleagei\romannumeral#1\expandafter\relax
  \else
    \errmessage{Invalid number}%
  \fi}
\def\Middleagei#1#2{%
  \ifx#2\relax
    \expandafter\Middleageii\expandafter#1%
  \else
    #1\expandafter\Middleagei\expandafter#2%
  \fi}
\def\Middleageii#1{%
  \expandafter\if\string i#1%
    j%
  \else
    #1%
  \fi}

\Middleage{100}

\Middleage{128}

\Middleage{41}
```

We read two tokens from the expansion of `\romannumeral#1\relax`; if the second is `\relax`, then we are at the end; so we have to decide if the last token of the Roman numeral is `i`; if it is, we print `j`, otherwise the character.

### Using this for representing counters in LaTeX

Add to the code above also

```
\makeatletter
\def\MAroman#1{\expandafter\@MAroman\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\def\@MAroman#1{\expandafter\Middleage\expandafter{\number#1}}
\makeatother
```

Now

```
\pagenumbering{MAroman}
\newcounter{mycount}
\renewcommand{\themycount}{\MAroman{mycount}}
```

will work as expected.

### Different version

The following version will print "i", "ij", "iij", "iv", "v", "vi", "vij" and so on (a final "i" becomes "j" only if preceded by "i").

```
\makeatletter
\def\Middleage#1{\expandafter\@middleage\expandafter{\number#1}}
\def\@middleage#1{%
  \ifnum#1>\z@
    \expandafter\@middle@ge\romannumeral#1\expandafter @\expandafter @%
  \else
    \errmessage{Invalid number}%
  \fi}
\def\@middle@ge#1#2#3{%
  \if#2@%
    #1%
  \else
    \expandafter\@middl@@ge\expandafter#1\expandafter#2\expandafter#3%
  \fi}
\def\@middl@@ge#1#2#3{%
  \if#3@%
    \expandafter\@m@ddl@@ge\expandafter#1\expandafter#2%
  \else
    #1\expandafter\@middle@ge\expandafter#2\expandafter#3%
  \fi}
\def\@m@ddl@@ge#1#2{%
  \expandafter\if\string i#2%
    \expandafter\if\string i#1%
      ij%
    \else
      #1#2%
    \fi
    \expandafter\@gobble
  \else
    #1#2\expandafter\@gobble
  \fi}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Nice way to catch the last letter of the argument, I was going to try it out with a loop and `@cdr`. Me thinks though that this is not the only difference in Middle Age Roman, one will have to build a more complicated algo to get other alphabet letters in.

Comment: This works like a charm for the whole range of values! Alas, I can't still use it for page numbering (is that what you meant by "not expandable"?)...

Comment: @mpr The first version was not expandable; the present one is and I've added the code for representing counters with it. Of course it's not perfect, as 1 is represented as j.

Comment: @egreg Sorry, but I can't seem to get it to work with page numbers... using `\pagenumbering{MAroman}` still displays the "normal" roman numerals. One being represented as "j" is ok as far as I can tell :)

Comment: @mpr Where are you putting `\pagenumbering{MAroman}`? If *before* `\frontmatter` it won't work.

Comment: As a matter of fact, I was putting it _before_... shame on me, you're absolutely right.