# Problem with hyperref's pagebackref, modroman and thebibliography

Tags: bibliographies, hyperref, warnings, back-referencing, roman-numerals

Following @yiannis-lazarides comment [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32037/middle-age-roman-numerals-formatting), I decided to use the `modroman` package for my frontmatters.

In my actual project I don't have that many references, and thus decided to use the `thebibliography` environment.

The problem is that I'm also using `hyperref` with the `pagebackrefs` option enabled, and this gives me some *very* strange warnings; not strange because of the warning *per se*, but rather because of when it happens (which baffles me).

The warning itself is:

```
name{page.xiij} has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one
```

and its raised when LaTeX is typesetting the pagebackrefs in question.

A minimal working example (exercising the warnings further) follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[pagebackref]{hyperref}
\usepackage{modroman}
\begin{document}
  \frontmatter
  \renewcommand{\thepage}{\texorpdfstring{\modroman{page}}{\roman{page}}}
  \setcounter{page}{10}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\cite{bib}, consectetur adipiscing elit.\clearpage
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\cite{bib}, consectetur adipiscing elit.\clearpage
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\cite{bib}, consectetur adipiscing elit.\clearpage
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\cite{bib}, consectetur adipiscing elit.\clearpage
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\cite{bib}, consectetur adipiscing elit.\clearpage
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\cite{bib}, consectetur adipiscing elit.\clearpage
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\cite{bib}, consectetur adipiscing elit.\cleardoublepage
  \begin{thebibliography}{9}
    \bibitem{bib}
      A.~N.~Author.
      Some title here.
      \emph{Another one here}, (12):3--5,
      September 1990.

  \end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Thoughts anyone? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that **hyperref** is using the two distinct representations when doing its business and gets out of synch when `\modroman{page}` and `\roman{page}` differ.

With `\renewcommand{\thepage}{\modroman{page}}` the error does not show; you'll get `xiij` also in the bookmarks, but it doesn't seem much of a problem. Happily, `\modroman` is completely expandable.

Comment: Thanks for explaining what's going on! I still don't understand... the link generated in the backreferences of the affected citations point to the first page no matter where they're cited... is there any way to fix this?

Comment: The backreferences works fine for me if I use Enricos suggestion. (current miktex 2.9.) Btw: In your minimal example there should be an empty line before `\end{bibliography}` to enable the backreferences.

Comment: @mpr Remember that back references need that each bibliography entry is followed by a blank line (you're missing it and you should be receiving an error message).

Comment: Edited to add blank line after bibliography entry ;)  still, backreferences are pointing to the first output page... @ulrike-fischer what suggestion are you referring to?

Comment: @mpr: I mean the `\renewcommand{\thepage}{\modroman{page}}`. I'm using `hyperref 2011/10/01 v6.82j`

Comment: :facepalm:! I really can't remember why I even wrote that `\texorpdfstring` in the first place!  Apologies.